# 'LIKE' not working in SQL statement in code, but is in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a search box that searches by customerID, their full name, or a part of their name. I am using 'LIKE' to search using part of their name.

I can search by customerID or full name no problem, but if I enter `Sam`, no records for `Samuel` appear.

I am doing below in my SQL statement in the code, but get no records when searching for parts of names.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM  customers WHERE firstName LIKE '%@name%' OR lastName LIKE '%@name%' OR (firstName + ' ' + lastName)=@name OR customerID=@id ORDER BY customerID desc";
SqlParameter[] spParameter = new SqlParameter[2];
spParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@id", (int.TryParse(searchTb.Text, out int i) ? i : 0));
spParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@name", searchTb.Text);
```

I put this query into SSMS

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE firstName LIKE '%Sam%' 
   OR lastName LIKE '%lap%' 
   OR (firstName + ' ' + lastName) = 'Bob Tom' 
   OR customerID = 1
```

When I hit execute it shows me my expected output. I get all records with first names that contain `sam`, last names with `lap`, etc.

Is there something I should be doing code wise to fix my output, am I using my parameters correctly with like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is the parameter substitution.  Try treating the value just like a string constant:

```
WHERE firstName LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
```

Note:  No single quotes.

Or, alternatively, put the wildcards in in the application:

```
WHERE firstName LIKE @name
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it would be a simple fix!